# webkit-transform:translate3d and div 100% height

Tags: webkit, css, mobile-webkit

I'm running into a weird issue on Safari and Chrome (mobile/desktop) that when I apply a global style for webkit-transform:translate3d, div background colors and 100% height set in the style no longer work.  Additionally, setting top:0px and bottom:0px fail too.  When I remove the global -webkit-transform style, everything works as expected.  Any ideas?

```
    *
    {
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
        margin:0px;
        -webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);

    }
```

Full sample

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sample</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

     <style type="text/css">
        *
        {
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
            margin:0px;
            -webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);

        }
        body {
        height:100%;
        }

    </style>


</head>
<body >

   <div id="myDiv" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:320px;height:100%;bottom:0px;display:block;background:black;color:black;border:1px solid black;">
            adsfasdf
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you'd want to apply a transformation to everything (perhaps you want the GPU to kick in?) in any case, the transformation on the html is causing this. You can solve it easily:

```
*:not(html)
    {
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
        margin:0px;
        -webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);

    }
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/Wv5Mx/

Comment: On mobile devices (mostly iOS), you get screen flickering issues using -webkit-transform.  The only way to get rid of it in one application was to apply that style globally.  I tried to add it to elements individually, but still had the flickering.  Thanks though, this does fix the problem I submitted.

Comment: Hmm, this actually does remove the flicker for me, but this code instead crashes mobile Safari on iPad... Anyone?

Comment: Try applying  -webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0) only to the elements you are going to animate instead of everything except the html tag (that's what *:not(html) means).

Answer (score 2):

You should try using the following.

```
.hwa {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000;
  -webkit-transform-style: flat;
}
```

only on the div.

```
<div class="hwa"></div>
```

This way you don't have to worry about descendent selectors which uses a lot of CPU before compositing the layers and creating the GPU. Keep in mind that GPU acceleration uses 4x the memory of standard CPU animation (reflow / recalculate / paint )

Also you should make sure that you help out the Browser as much as possible, this means use width: 100%, height: 100% sparingly since it takes a lot of CPU to figure out how to construct the composite layers prior to GPU taking over.